# Determine congruent transformation between a pair of rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

If a pair of $3\times 3$ rotation matrices $R_A$ and $R_B$ satisfies $$R_B = R_C R_A R_C^T $$ where  $R_C$ is an unknown $3\times 3$ rotation matrix. Can $R_C$ be uniquely determined by the congruent relation between $R_A$ and $R_B$?

I guess the answer is yes because we can uniquely determine $R_C$ from the relation $R_B = R_C R_A$ and the congruent relation doesn't introduce more freedoms.

Comment: But if you have $R_B=R_CR_A$, then how can you also have $R_B=R_CR_AR_C^T$?

Comment: I mean  $R_B=R_C R_A R_C^T$ and $R_B=R_C R_A$ have the same number of unknown variables, since in the latter $R_C$ can be uniquely determined, so does in the former equations